# @html.FileFor Returns Null MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to upload a file with mvc4 and im getting null returned in my controller for the file upload. Can anyone see why please?

View Model

```
public class PostExtendedWithImage
{
    public Post post { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Wall", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
    UpdateTargetId = "newPost"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  


    <fieldset>
        <legend>Post</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">

        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.post.Username, new { Value = User.Identity.Name })

        </div>

        @Html.FileFor(model => model.file)


            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.post.PostContent)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.post.PostContent)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.post.PostContent)
            </div>

            @{
    TempData["returnURL"] = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            }
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="postStatus" value="Create" />
            </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult CreatePost(PostExtendedWithImage VM)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (VM.file == null)
                {
                   // Do stuff     

                }

                else
                {
                    //Save file to DB
                }


                return PartialView("_NewStatusPartial",VM);

            }

            return PartialView("All",VM);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot upload a file via an ajax form. There are workarounds for this.. but you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. Could you please point me in the direction of the workarounds?

Comment: Jquery fileupload for example: http://plugins.jquery.com/blueimp-file-upload-jquery-ui/. The workarounds either use `iframe`s, or Flash objects to upload files asynchronously. A straight up ajax form in MVC cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous File submission using `Ajax.BeginForm` may not be possible. You can use 3rd party plugins to do this ajax submission.

You can use [jQuery Forms Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) in this context.
[See](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit) how can you do [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit) using this plugin.

```
// bind to the form's submit event 
    $('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
        // inside event callbacks 'this' is the DOM element so we first 
        // wrap it in a jQuery object and then invoke ajaxSubmit 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        // !!! Important !!! 
        // always return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false; 
    });
```

Its so simple to do. Give a try!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with `Ajax.BeginForm`, however, if you are uploading a file, you usually need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` tag.

Not really sure if this applies in AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have included it now but still produces the same error.

Comment: This isn't possible with an Ajax form.